# How to call javascript function in the parent page from user control?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have some ASP.NET user control named `myUserControl`.

I also have some aspx page named `myAspxPage`.

`myAspxPage` contains `myUserControl` and also `myAspxPage` contains this javascript function:

```
     function SetProgressBar() 
     {
          //some logic          
     }
```

at some point I need to call `SetProgressBar` javascipt function when this button:

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="prevItem" runat="server" ToolTip="previous" Style="color: #000000;" OnClientClick="to call SetProgressBar function"> << </asp:LinkButton>
```

is clicked in `myUserControl`.

I tryed this:

```
  OnClientClick="parent.SetProgressBar()"
```

and this:

```
OnClientClick="SetProgressBar()"
```

But examples above not work.

So my question is any idea how can I call javascript function in the parent page from user control?

Comment: "examples above not work" - based on what? The second variant is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you add

```
ClientIdMode="static"
```

to your button and take out the OnClientClick="" so it looks like this:

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="prevItem" runat="server" ToolTip="previous" Style="color: #000000;" ClientIdMode="static"> << </asp:LinkButton>
```

and then use onclick directly in the javascript like this:

```
document.getElementById("prevItem").onclick = function SetProgressBar(){

// some logic

}
```

That should work...

Answer (score 1):

Usercontrol is not a separate page when it is added inside any aspx page everything is rendered as a single page so in short there is no parent-child kind of thing between aspx page and usercontrol.

You should be able to call any javascript function from usercontrol.

ClientIDMode=static is not required if you are calling a function using onClientClient=.

So to test whether the function is being triggered or not, please put an alert in the first line of the function and see if it gets alert or not.